# Pandas Series argument function memoization

Tags: python, pandas, memoization, mutable

I want to memoize a function with mutable parameters (Pandas Series objects). Is there any way to accomplish this?

Here's a simple Fibonacci example, the parameter is a Pandas Series where the first element represents the sequence's index.

Example:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n.iloc[0] == 1 or n.iloc[0] == 2:
        return 1
    min1 = n.copy()
    min1.iloc[0] -=1
    min2 = n.copy()
    min2.iloc[0] -= 2 
    return fib(min1) + fib(min2)
```

Call function:

```
fib(pd.Series([15,0]))
```

Result:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

The intended use is more complex, so I posted this useless but simple example.

Comment: May we see your code?

Comment: Sure, I've just posted some code

Comment: What is your question? Why you cannot hash mutable values?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to reuse overlapping subproblems in a recursive function. I know mutable values can't be hashed but is there an alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: Yeah: hash `n.iloc[0]` which seem to be the argument you're really interested in.

Comment: In the real problem I'm interested in the whole series

Comment: Are you looking to memoize by object identity rather than equality? That's not hard—just use the `id` function in generating your key—but whether or not it's useful depends on your problem.

Comment: how about by equality?

Comment: Alternatively, if you're looking to memoize by equality over some fields that are mutable, but you know you aren't going to mutate them during the lifetime of the cache so it's OK, you need to "freeze" those fields—e.g., copy a list into a tuple, or create an unsafe but useful  `__hash__` method in the class (or a safe one with an API for freezing an instance so it raises if hashed before frozen), etc.

Comment: And I suspect your next question is going to be how to efficiently and simply create a frozen equivalent to a Pandas series… which I don't know the answer to, but you may want to search around on that, and ask a specific question on that if you can't find an answer.

Comment: You can obviously do that by wrapping up the series with a frozen-series-holder that manually computes a hash when constructed by, e.g., hashing tuples of tuples of the values, and then working with those holders everywhere, but there may be a much simpler way.

Comment: @abarnert That might be the solution to my problem, thank you so much!

Comment: @JorgeBarrios If you find a simpler way to freeze a pandas series, you probably want to either write and accept an answer here, or suggest closing your question as a dup (if you found your answer on SO and it’s just obvious how it applies). If you have to build an ugly wrapper, you might want to post _that_ as an answer once you get it working. (Because either way, I’m sure you’re not the only person who will ever have this problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a wrapper to replace the Pandas Series argument with a tuple (frozen equivalent) as @abarnert and @Calvin suggested. Since tuples are immutable, the function can now be memoized.

```
def freeze_series(f):
    def wrapper(series):
        return f(tuple(series.to_dict(OrderedDict).items()))
    return wrapper
```

Here's a normal function to unfreeze the tuple back into a Pandas Series:

```
def unfreeze_series(frozen_series):
    return pd.Series(OrderedDict((x, y) for x, y in frozen_series))
```

It can be implemented like this to solve the question example:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@freeze_series
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    n = unfreeze_series(n)
    if n.iloc[0] == 1 or n.iloc[0] == 2:
        return 1
    min1 = n.copy()
    min1.iloc[0] -=1
    min2 = n.copy()
    min2.iloc[0] -= 2 
    return fib(min1) + fib(min2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Several options:

- Convert the mutable objects to something immutable such as a string or tuple.
- Create a hash of the mutable objects and use that as the memo dict key. Risk of hash clashes.
- Create an immutable subclass which implements the __hash__() function.